# VB.NET Replacing a String with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm having a few problems with Regular Expressions in VB.NET.

I have a String like this one: `"[Type=User][User=Hello]Thats the message"`

I want to have the `"Thats the message"` part, so I thought that the best way to do that was replacing `"[Type=User][User=Hello]"` for `""`.

Notes:

- `"Thats the message"` is always at the end of the String and it can be `""` (without characters).
- `[Type=XXXX]` can be anything, I mean,  it can be `[Type=Password]`, `[Type=Message]`...

So, here is what I did:

```
Dim regOptions As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline
Regex.Replace(buffer, "^(.*)[^\]]*$", "", regOptions)
```

It doesn't work, the string 'buffer' is not modified.

Comment: Surly you could use `String.Split` for this, using `]` as the delimiter character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation of that overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) it will return the resulting string (after all, in .Net strings are immutable).

So, instead, try:

```
buffer = Regex.Replace(buffer, "^(.*)[^\]]*$", "", regOptions)
```

Comment: Right. Also, I don't think that pattern will work. Why not just `\[.*\]` ?

Comment: A better pattern might be `\[([^\]]+)\]`, but the reason the replacement wasn't doing anything was that the result was never read...